# find grep -E gives error: find: unknown predicate `-E'

Tags: 18.04, grep, find

I am running the command (on Ubuntu 18.04)

```
find . \| grep -E "(\_\_pycache__\|\.pyc\|\.pyo$)" \| xargs rm -rf
```

and I get the error

```
find: unknown predicate '-E'
```

I used to run this command on previous installations with no problem.

Comment: `find | grep -E '(__pycache__|.pyc|.pyo)$' | xargs echo rm -rf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used to run this command on previous installations with no problem

I don't know how is that possible because it's a completely wrong
syntax - you should use `|`, not `\|` , and also there is no need to use `grep` and `rm` separately.
It should be:

```
find . \( -name "*__pycache__" -o -name "*.pyc" -o -name "*.pyo" \) -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove files using extglob and globstar:

```
$ rm -i **/@(__pycache__|*.pyc|*.pyo)
```